# How to post an xml file?

Tags: python, linux

I have an xml file named test.xml. I want to post the content(http/xml) of that file to a specific IP. I'm doing manual POST. Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: This post is incomplete, please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use requests module in python. will get your job easy.

example:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://192.168.3.45:8080/api/v2/event/log'

data = {"eventType": "AAS_PORTAL_START", "data": {"uid": "hfe3hf45huf33545", "aid": "1", "vid": "1"}}
params = {'sessionKey': '9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103', 'format': 'xml', 'platformId': 1}

requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Above is JSON, i need it for http/xml

Comment: import requests

xml = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<a>б</a>"""
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} # set what your server accepts
print requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=xml, headers=headers).text